# IMACROS how to replace br command

Tags: csv, replace, imacros

Halo friends, I want to ask for some question about imacros command. i really new here, this is the case:

So i want to extract first all Text and some text, 
1. first i want extract all TXT this is my commad:

`TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=COLSPAN:"4" EXTRACT=TXT`
`SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=RESULT.csv`

```
<tr class="detail-middle">
 <td colspan="4">
  <span class="font-bold">Address</span>
   <p>
     <strong>Orin Fade</strong>
     <br>
     19 rue marciere
     <br>
     Lyon
     <br>
     Lyon
     <br>
     France
     <br>
     Phone Number: +33 0478372730
   </p>
 </td>
</tr>
```

The effect is data on result.csv create new line on every `<br>`, i hope i can change the `<br>` into space " " so the result is 1 line.

2. Can i just extract data between `<p> </p>` only ?
   because i don't know for "TYPE=" and what "ATTR="

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to extract the data only between `<p>` and `</p>` by means of the following line:

```
TAG XPATH="//td[@colspan='4'][1]/p" EXTRACT=TXT
```

In order to replace `<br>`'s with spaces " " you should use the `EVAL` command:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=COLSPAN:"4" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\\n/g, ' ').trim();")
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=RESULT.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Shugar, but when i run the command (XPATH), it have nothing, i look imacros looking for something,, and he don't get it.